# How to use a PreparedStatement as a subquery in another prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, h2

I'm using a `PreparedStatement` in my code to make queries.  For example:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = db.con.prepareStatement("select id from nodes where x>? and x<? and y>? and y<?");           
stmt.setDouble(1, x1); 
... //set a value for each param 1 thru 4
```

And now I have another query that wants to use the exact same query above as a subquery.  So I could do:

```
PreparedStatement stmt2 = db.con.prepareStatement("select id from edges where startNodeId in 
(select id from nodes where x>? and x<? and y>? and y<?)");
```

But that's repetitive and I'm likely to modify the first `PreparedStatement` and want those changes to propagate to the second one.  Is there a way to set a prepared statement to be a subquery in another statement?

Perhaps something akin to `stmt2.setPreparedStatement(2, stmt)`?

Comment: No can do. But nothing prevents you from reusing a string constant with the query text. You can even write a helper method for setting the 4 parameters.

Comment: As @Andreas says, and maybe use named parameters for clarity so you can reference them properly?

Comment: @KoosGadellaa `PreparedStatement` doesn't support named parameters, only positional.

Comment: You're right. Lost in Springlation again

Answer (score 1):

Simply combine both the queries into one single `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT x,y,z FROM tablez WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM "your first query")
```